# how to read data in file that is contained within a folder of a parent folder c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

We have folder "TDScript", in which there are let's say 11 sub folders and in these folders we have 23 JavaScript files in each one.

Now I want to replace the word "Table" in every java script file to their respective folder's name.

I through this code. We are able to read only file names but not the data within the files.

The code:

```
protected void BindGridview()
{
    string strpath = @"e:\vs\tdscripts";
    string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(strpath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(strpath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string f in folders)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(f);
        foreach (string item in files)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGridview();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, I think following should work for you

```
protected void BindGridview()
{
    string strpath = @"e:\vs\tdscripts";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(strpath);

    foreach (var file in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName, Encoding.Default);
        content = content.Replace("Table", file.Directory.Name);
        File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, content, Encoding.Default);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'll run it and 'll comment the result

Answer (score 0):

You are just getting `File`'s and `Folder`'s names which are in that folder.

To read the content of the file you can use [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) method or any other one from System.IO for reading File's data.